# learning Git: tracking vs. setting upstream (-u) for remotes?

Tags: git, github

I am learning Git and am attempting to understand the difference between "tracking" a remote and defining an "upstream" relationship with it (with the `-u` tag).

For master to origin/master, I have been using

```
git push origin master
```

which seems to automatically define a relationship (although I am not sure what it is).

For branches, I have been using

```
git branch newbranch
git push -u origin newbranch
```

I know this sets an upstream relationship, but again I don't understand the distinction.

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: Short answer: no difference. [Longer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33503279/63209) answer: you _track_ an **upstream**. Uber long, but very informative answer: grab some coffee and [read on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509159/63209).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Both answers here are correct, but I'll describe the underlying mechanism, because until I found out what it was, I found the whole notion of "tracking" quite mysterious.

Git breaks up this "tracking" information into two parts: the name of the remote—usually the word `origin`, like you're using—and then the name that git commands *on that remote* use to name the branch.<sup>1</sup>  In other words, if you have login access to the remote, and you log in over there and go into the repository, you might run `git log master` to see what has been committed.

If you peek into your `.git/config` file, you will see, for each local branch that's "tracking" something, these two parts.  For instance, let's say you had a local branch named `experiment`, that you have set up to track `origin/master`.  This would result in:

```
[branch "experiment"]
    remote = origin
    merge = master
```

But there is one more part to this tracking-branch stuff: when you run `git fetch origin`, and there's something new on branch `master` on `origin`, the `fetch` step updates your local `origin/master`.  This name—with the remote-name `origin` first, then a slash `/`, then the branch name as it appears on the remote—is how you can see what's happened on the remote.  After your `git fetch` is done, it copies the remote's branch-names (and their corresponding SHA-1s for their branch-tips) to your local repository, renaming them with the remote-name in front.

It's actually the `git fetch` step that updates `origin/master` and so on, and only once that's done, does this "tracking" stuff have any useful effect.  Git can now tell you that you're ahead and/or behind by some number of commits.  And, you can now run a command like `git log origin/master` to see what's happening there—or more interestingly, `git log --oneline master..origin/master` to see "their" commits that you don't have yet: essentially, "what fetch brought in"—and `git log --oneline origin/master..master` to see "your" commits that they don't have yet.  (If you've already done a merge or rebase, it's too late to see what your fetch brought in, because now you have what they had then, as a result of your merge-or-rebase.)

The oddball in all of this is `git pull`.  The `git pull` command is really just a short-cut that runs `git fetch` first, and then runs `git merge` (or, if you redirect it, `git rebase`).  To do these steps separately, you run `git fetch origin`, then `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master`.  For historical reasons,<sup>2</sup> `git pull` takes the *remote*'s name for the branch, in this case `master`, rather than the name it winds up being renamed-to in your repository.

---

So, with that as background, let's look at some commands:

- `git fetch remote`: This doesn't need any branch names at all.  It calls up the given remote, asks it where all its branches are now, and updates your repository, recording all these updates underneath the `origin/` names (so as not to affect any of your local branches).  In other words, this updates the names your branches may (or may not) be tracking, but it doesn't need to know anything about what is or isn't tracking what.
- `git status`: If it says you're "on branch X", and branch *`X`* is tracking `origin/X`, `git status` can also tell you if you have, on your *`X`*, commits that are not on `origin/X`, and vice versa.
- `git merge` and `git rebase`: These need some way to know what to merge, or what to rebase onto.  You can name it explicitly, but if you tell your git that your branch `X` is tracking `origin/X`, then whenever you're on branch `X`, `git merge` or `git rebase` will know what to do.
- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/X`: This is the main command that sets or changes what your *current* branch is tracking.  In other words, if you're on branch `X` now, this updates `branch.X.remote` and `branch.X.merge` for you, so that you don't have to use two separate `git config` commands.  You can also use `git branch --unset-upstream` to *remove* the tracking information.
- `git push`: if you give it no additional information, it uses the current branch's "remote"—the first half of its tracking info—to decide which remote to call up.  Whether or not you give `git push` a remote name, the next part depends on whether you give it a "refspec".  If you don't, `git push` uses `push.default` to decide what refspec to use.

#### Wait, what's a refspec?

The second-simplest form of a refspec is just two branch names with a colon between them, like `master:master`.  For `git push`, the name on the left is your branch name, and the name on the right is their—the other git's—branch name.  If you omit the `:` you get the simplest form, where the remote-side name—the one that would follow the `:`—is chosen by a somewhat complicated process (described in the [`git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)), which actually depends on more configuration variables and whether you've set an upstream.

What about `git push -u`?  That's just a convenient shortcut: in much the way that `git branch --set-upstream-to` is a shortcut for doing two `git config` commands, `git push -u refspec` is a shortcut for doing a push, and then doing a `git branch --set-upstream-to` as well.  You must give `push` a refspec for this to do anything useful.

What if you give a "half refspec" like `master`?  Well, as noted above, the name your git chooses to give to the remote's git is found by a complicated process, but *if you haven't set an upstream yet* (which is fairly likely if you're doing `git push -u` in the first place) it's going to be the same as your local name.  So `git push -u origin master` probably "means" `git push -u origin master:master`, and *that* then means `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`, in the end.

If you give a fuller refspec, like `git push -u origin experiment:feature`, this will push your `experiment` branch to `origin`, asking `origin` to call it `feature`, and then do a `--set-upstream-to origin/feature`.  Note that at this point, the upstream name of your local branch differs from the local name.  Git is fine with this; just be sure you are, too. :-)

There are more clever tricks that git has:

- If you run `git checkout branch` and *`branch`* does not yet exist, *and* there's a single "obvious" remote-tracking branch such as `origin/branch`, git will create a new, local *`branch`* that is already tracking `origin/branch`.  (That is, the local branch will have its `remote` set to `origin` and its `merge` set to *`branch`*.)
- If you run `git branch local-name remote-tracking-name`, git will automatically set up the local branch to track the corresponding remote-tracking branch.  (You can configure git as to whether you want this, but that's the default.)

Summary: `git fetch` updates the things that tracking uses (the `origin/*` entries, for remote `origin`).  Once that's done—including if it's done by using `git pull`, which runs `git fetch`<sup>3</sup>—*then* you see more information from commands like `git status`; and commands like `git rebase` use it to know how to do the rebase, without your having to tell it anything more.

There's one more interesting twist: any branch's "upstream" can be in your own local repository.  To get this, you set the `remote` for that branch to `.` (a literal dot), and the `merge` to the name of the branch.  You don't have to know how to do this, because you can do `git branch --set-upstream-to master`, for instance, to make your current branch track your own `master`.

#### "Incoming" and "outgoing"

Mercurial users may wonder how you can get the effect of `hg incoming` or `hg outgoing`.  The former tells you what your upstream has, that you don't.  The latter tells you what you have, that they don't.  As it turns out, this is easy to do in modern git, because git has a special syntax, `@{u}`, to find the current branch's upstream.

In other words, if you're on `master` and `master` tracks `origin/master`, `@{u}` (which you can spell out as `@{upstream}`) is just another way to write `origin/master`.  So `origin/master..master` is just a longer way to write `@{u}..master`.  *And*, if you're on `master`, `HEAD` also names `master`, and omitting a branch name tells git to use `HEAD`, so `@{u}..` suffices.

As noted above, after you've run `git fetch` on the appropriate remote, you can use `git log` to find "what they have that you don't" and "what you have that they don't".  You do have to run this `git fetch` step (and *do not* want a merge or rebase to occur at this point).

So:

```
git config --global alias.incoming '!git fetch && git log --oneline ..@{u}'
git config --global alias.outgoing '!git fetch && git log --oneline @{u}..'
```

(in some shells you may need a `\` in front of the `!`, or other quoting tricks, and it may be easier to just insert the aliases with your editor by running `git config --global --edit`).

You can, of course, change the `--oneline` part to whatever options you prefer.  (And I like to leave the `git fetch` step for me to manually run myself anyway, which simplifies the alias to just `alias.incoming = log --oneline ..@{u}`, for instance.<sup>4</sup>  This mainly just avoids constantly pestering the upstream.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you keep your branch names the same as theirs, you don't get a chance to see this.  But once you start using branches heavily, you'll probably wind up with several branches that all track the same upstream, and then it really matters.

<sup>2</sup>`git pull` actually predates remotes and remote-tracking branches.  It still has all kinds of weirdness because of this.

<sup>3</sup>If your git version is older than 1.8.4, when `git pull` runs `git fetch`, the `fetch` step *doesn't* update remote-tracking branches.  This was intended as a feature, but it was a bad feature, and newer git versions update.  This does mean, though, that if you have an old git, you should be wary of using the `pull` script: it's an inconvenient convenience.

<sup>4</sup>Fixed in an edit: I accidentally wrote `alias.incoming = git log ...`.  Git aliases are assumed to be other git commands (like `log`), so you want to *leave out* the `git` part, *unless* the whole alias starts with an exclamation point `!`, in which case the whole alias is passed to the shell to run.  I actually forget, now, how aliases worked back when all the commands were spelled like `git-log`, `git-branch`, `git-fetch`, and so on, but it must have been less complicated... :-)

Answer (score 10):

`git push origin master` explicitly says "push the local branch 'master' to the remote named 'origin'". This does not define a persistent relationship, it just executes a push this one time. Note that the remote branch is assumed to be named "master".

`git push -u origin master` is the same thing, except it first adds a persistent tracking relationship between your local branch "master" and the remote named "origin". As before, it is assumed the remote branch is named "master".

If you have done a push with `-u` already, then the relationship is already defined. In the future, you can simply say `git push` or `git pull`, and git will automatically use the defined remote tracking branch without being told explicitly.

You can view your tracking relationships with `git branch -vv`, which will list your local branches along with their current HEAD commit and, if one is set, the remote tracking branch. Here is an example.

```
$ git branch -vv
* master                   58a0d68 [origin/master] Fix CSS regression bug
  migration_tool           2a24ff7 [origin/migration_tool] [#906] Fix table layout problem
  topic-ajax-timeouts      fe854f2 Adjust timeouts to be more realistic
```

Here are shown 3 branches along with their current HEAD commits and commit messages. On the first two, there is a tracking branch specified, but the third branch is not tracking a remote branch.

Comment: So tracking and upstream are the same thing? Does `git push origin master` implicitly include a -u tag?

Comment: @eabates No, it is not implicit. I edited my answer to be more clear, and to show how you can view what your current upstream relationships are.

Answer (score 6):

"Tracking" and "upstream" are related terms. "Tracking" means associating a branch of your local repository with an *upstream branch*, i.e. a branch that lives in a remote repository. For instance,

```
git push -u origin newbranch
```

sets up the tracking information of your local `newbranch` so that the `newbranch` that lives in the remote repo called `origin` (i.e. the remote repo that your local repo knows under the nickname `origin`) is considered the upstream branch of your local `newbranch`... and carries out the push.

If you obtained your local repository by cloning it, you don't need to run

```
git push -u origin master
```

because `origin/master` is already set up as `master`'s upstream branch. In other words, `master` is already set to track `origin/master`.

Comment: So they are basically the same thing? Is there a default relationship, for example when writing `git push origin master`? Does that place origin/master upstream and local master downstream?

Comment: @eabates no, it does nothing except push `master` to `origin`.