# git push rejected: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally

Tags: git, bitbucket

```
 [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.wpengine.com:production/<sitename>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

i am seeing this error when i try pushing the changes to the production.
i did try all the possibilities suggested still i encounter this.

not sure what is causing the issue. is it related to the, legacy staging pushed to production creating an issue?

stuck on this for hours, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are all possibilities that you tried? Did you try the suggested solution: `git pull origin master`?

Comment: yes, i did.
its says: Already up to date.  But still i see the error after pushing again

Comment: That reminds me of 2015 torek's explanation to a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/q/33509667/6309

Comment: please add the output of this command `git branch --all -vv | grep "origin/master"` to your question

Comment: If you tried `git pull origin master` and still it did not work, try `git pull origin refs/heads/master` instead. There is a small chance that `master` matches another ref like `refs/for/master` which is in the front of `refs/heads/master`. And you can use `git ls-remote | grep master` to check if there is any suspicious `master` ref.

Comment: @toydarian 

* master                 05a30f8 [origin/master] interactive IR
  remotes/origin/HEAD    -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master  05a30f8 interactive IR
  remotes/origin/staging 4691308 commiting

^ this is the output for git branch --all -vv

Comment: Check in bitbucket, if `master` there actually points to ` 05a30f8`

Comment: And run `git remote -v` to check if the push `origin` and the fetch `origin` are 2 different remote repos.

Comment: @ElpieKay, both fetch and push origin points to the same remote

Comment: @toydarian, yes master points to '05a30f8'