# How to programatically inspect remote tracking information upstream?

Tags: git

My question is similar to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310294/how-to-create-git-remote-tracking-branch)

I pushed a local branch to a server, creating it for the first time on that server and setting it as the local branch's upstream with `--upstream`. I am having trouble extracting tracking information programatically from the upstream without making unecessary changes to the local git repository. For example, I would like to know the commit hash that the `HEAD` of the upstream is pointing to.

Here's how I created that remote branch and set as upstream:

```
$ git push --set-upstream sshname:/user/project.git
```

I can `git pull`, `git push` etc. just fine. However, I have a script in my `.bashrc` that inspects the hash of the latest commit on the upstream server and compares it with my current branche's hash. (This is used to prettify the prompt with a colorscheme that help me quickly see whether I remembered to push a repo to the server, or whether I'm on a detached head, etc). The script works fine on most local repositories, where it gets that remote `HEAD` hash with

```
$ git rev-parse "$(git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null)"@{upstream}

> fatal: upstream branch 'refs/heads/master' not stored as a remote-tracking branch
```

As you see, it fails with the claim that there the branch on the remote is not stored locally as a remote tracking branch.

I looked for various suggestions on StackExchange on how to get around this, including [How to create git Remote-Tracking Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310294/how-to-create-git-remote-tracking-branch) and [learning Git: tracking vs. setting upstream (-u) for remotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503080/learning-git-tracking-vs-setting-upstream-u-for-remote). Nothing helps. Many of the suggestions are just wrong, with people conflating `remotes`, `remote tracking branches` and `upstream urls`.

---

Here is the output of various commands that people might suggest:

```
$ git remote -vv
> [no output]
```

```
$ git branch -vva
> * master <HASH> <COMMIT_MSG>
```

```
$ git fetch -a
> From sshname:/user/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This is the first one that shows the information I'm looking for. But it's not in a machine-parseable format and there's no `--porcelain`. **It's also wrong.** The real URL ends in `.git`. And the server does actually need this `.git` suffix; it cannot be ignored.

```
$ git ls-remote
> From sshname:/user/project.git
<HASH>        HEAD
<HASH>        refs/heads/master
```

The correct URL now, but again not machine-parseable.

I can also run 'destructive' operations (not OK for scripting) in order to fetch this information indirectly in a similar fashion:

```
$ git pull
> From sshname:/user/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Wrong URL again.

```
$ git push
> Pushing to sshname:/user/project.git
To gitea:/murdock/dupmaster.git
 = [up to date]      master -> master
Everything up-to-date
```

Needless to say, I can hardly trust such inconsistent output for scripts. I need a `porcelain`-like output.

Now the closest solution I found was:

```
$ git config -l
> ...
branch.master.remote=sshname:/user/project.git
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Indicating that I could get the upstream 'URL' this way:

```
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
> sshname:/user/project.git
```

But still, I cannot probe the remote tracking information. Manually, I could add a git remote based on this 'URL' and then run `git fetch -a` and that (probably) would resolve my issue. But this is a 'destructive' process which alters the `git` repo. I'm trying to script something which doesn't make unecessary changes to the repos.

**How can I programatically fetch tracking information in a reliable way, without altering the git repo?**

I would settle for automatically creating remote tracking branches, if that were possible. But I do not want to create remotes (how would I name them automatically? etc).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have set up a Git repository in which *there is no remote*, as seen here:

> ```
> $ git remote -vv
> > [no output]
> ```

With no remote, there can be no remote-tracking names.  A remote-tracking name is produced by taking a branch name *from* some other Git repository, as seen on a repository found by accessing it through a "remote", and running it through the mapping provided under the given remote.

To *add* a remote *to* this repository:

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

(assuming you'd like to use the name `origin`; use any name you prefer here, but `origin` is the standard first one).  This will create the remote.  The remote now stores the URL, so that this:

> ```
> $ git config --get branch.master.remote
> > sshname:/user/project.git
> ```

will change.

To make that change happen, instead of (or after):

> ```
> $ git push --set-upstream sshname:/user/project.git
> ```

use:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Now instead of:

> ```
> $ git config --get branch.master.remote
> > sshname:/user/project.git
> ```

you will find that `branch.master.remote` simply contains `origin`.

The remote itself provides a *default fetch refspec:*

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

which will read:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Subsequent `git fetch origin` operations will create or update the names in the `refs/remotes/origin/` namespace: the remote-tracking names for the remote named `origin`, whose URL is stored in `remote.origin.url`.

(What's going on is that you're using the setup from Primeval Git, back in 2005 or so, before the concept of a *remote* was invented.  Without a remote, there can be no remote-tracking names.  Git still supports this mode, but it's unwise to use it since—as you've discovered—a lot of modern software really wants the features provided by having a remote.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, would you say it's not recommended to use `git push -u host.name:/path/to/repo` then? And instead our workflow should be to always add a remote, then push with `git push -u remote/branch`?

Comment: @Myridium: yes. Use a raw Git URL only when you are not going to use it further, otherwise save it as a `git remote add` step.